# Migrating from cmd to mac

Tags: batch, automation, command-line, scheduled-tasks, automator

For me it is quite easy to automate a jar file to run on a pc.

`java -jar "C:\...\mFilePath\myJar.jar"`

stick this into a cmd file, and schedule it.

Now, migrating over to a mac, i am unsure how to do this. I assumed the automator would be more straight forward, but i find it not to be. I must be doing something wrong.

Please, any advice is appreciated!!

Comment: If you have already searched this site and haven't found anything useful, you might also want to consider searching the [su] sister site. I actually find your question more relevant there than here and, accordingly, am voting to migrate it to that site.

Comment: ok, i can agree with that. i have voted as well. thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're not familiar with launchd you could also use cron, what is most commonly used under *nix. Just fire up Terminal and use "crontab -e" to add your job.

Format for crontab is

> min hour day month day-of-week command

For more information look at [Wikipedia :: Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule scripts to run with launch agents. (man launchd , man launchctl). [Lingon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lingon-3/id450201424?mt=12) is a useful resource.

Comment: Links I found useful for learning about `launchd` and `launchctl`: http://dustin.github.com/2010/02/28/running-processes.html, http://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs, http://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/launchd-examples-launchd-plist-file-examples-mac. Also, if you are a Ruby person, check out Mike Perham's [lunchy](https://github.com/mperham/lunchy).